# How to hide recent in the navigation

Tags: 2013, navigation

In SP2013 you have the recent entry in the navigation.
Is there an easy way to automatically hide/remove this entry?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did some additional research and found the answer myself.

```
var title = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:core,category_Recent", null, web.Language);
SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
foreach (SPNavigationNode node in nodes)
{
  if (node.Title.Equals(title))
  {
    node.Delete();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you put this code? I put it in a Feature Event Receiver in the FeatureActivated event, & it didn't work :(

Answer (score 6):

You can manually delete the header from:

> Site Settings-> Look and Feel -> Navigation

Comment: I am creating a webtemplate based on a teamsite. Do you know how this can be done by code?

Comment: What is the result you are looking for? Should the navigation be inherited from the parent site?

Comment: I already found and posted the answer I was looking for. Tnx for helping

Answer (score 5):

I have an out of the box solution.

1. *Settings -> Site contents
2. *Site permissions
3. *Create Group
4. Make a new group with no permissions.
5. Delete all users from the group.
6. *Settings -> Site contents
7. *Navigation
8. Select the "Recent" heading
9. *Edit
10. Set Audience = the group from step 4
11. *OK
12. *OK

Now only members of a group, with no members, are able to see the "Recent" heading.

Answer (score 1):

With Sharepoint Online (Office 365) you can delete the Recent from the menu by doing the following:

1. Select "Edit Links" at the bottom left of menu
2. Click "X" next to Recent" to delete it and save

**NOTE:** You'll need to recreate the menu links under "Recent" if you follow these steps. Under each app you'll need to toggle the on/off radio button for "Display this list on the Quick Launch?" in the General Settings.

Answer (score 1):

In SP13, just go to site settings > Look and Feel > Quick launch and click the recent link.  You'll have to put in a url before it will allow you to delete.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was to create a SharePoint group (I called mine "RemoveRecent") and have no users assigned to that group.

I then used this PowerShell script to add the "RemoveRecent" group into the "Audience Targeting" section of the "Recent" Quick Launch Navigation Link.

This effectively hides the menu item from everyone.

```
$Site = Get-SPSite "https://SITECOLLECTION/"

foreach ($Web in $Site.AllWebs)
    {
    $PublishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
    $QuickLaunchNav = $PublishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNodes
    $QuickLaunchHeading = $QuickLaunchNav | where {$_.Title -eq "Recent"} 

    if ($QuickLaunchHeading)
        {
        Write-Host $Web.Title "- " -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black -NoNewline
        $QuickLaunchHeading.Properties["Audience"] = "RemoveRecent"
        $QuickLaunchHeading.Update() 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery: [SharePoint 2013 - Remove Recent](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/b0b126fb-298b-469a-9a35-fb7abd50b997/sharepoint-2013-remove-recent-from-left-menu?forum=sharepointadmin)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".ms-core-listMenu-item:contains('Recent')").parent().hide();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Site Settings -> Quick Launch
   Select the Edit icon near Recent
2. Copy any valid url into the empty URL box (Recent item does not show a URL)
3. Click Delete (with an empty URL box, it would have given an error message)
4. Confirm deletion

It works in SharePoint 2013, not sure about the earlier versions

Answer (score -2):

I decided as follows:
Added the css code on the page that did not want to display the "Recent" menu:

```
div#zz12_V4QuickLaunchMenu ul#zz13_RootAspMenu li.static span.static span.additional-background{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Never do this, since the IDs get changed mostly between every page refresh and every user. Though they fall in a range like zz12 to zz14....., we may never know